# Excel VB: get the value checked/unchecked for a checkbox

Tags: vba

I'm not able to get the value of a checkbox..

I've googled a lot but I really can't find the error.

Anyway this is my code:

```
If printa.Checked = True Then
objDoc.PrintOut
Else
bjDoc.Close
End If
```

The chechbox's name in the Userform is "printa".

I get the error that it can't find the method or the object.

Any advice?

Thanks
Dennis

Comment: Use *IntelliSense* to browse an object's members in the code pane, or use the *Object Browser* (F2) to explore what's available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you want to use is `Value`:

```
If printa.Value = True Then
    objDoc.PrintOut
Else
    objDoc.Close
End If
```

(There's also a typo in your `objDoc.Close`)

Comment: thank you! the method "checked" comes from internet.. I also googled for "get checkbox value" .. anyway thanks!! :)

Comment: Note, `If printa.Value = True Then` is redundant. `If printa.Value Then` would be enough.